# Keeping an auto-updating clone of a bare git repository

Tags: linux, git

#### Here is what I did

```
cd /git
git init --bare repo
```

#### What I want to do

I want an auto-updating non-bare clone of the repository to be available at a different location e.g. `/srv/web/`. What I mean is that everytime someone does a `git push` the contents in `/srv/web/` should automatically update. Similarly, if the git repository is reverted back, then the files in `/srv/web` should also revert to that.

Comment: Perhaps `git flow` is a good start point.

Comment: bare or non-bare? your text says non-bare, but title says bare. please make a clarification.

Comment: the repository from which i have to clone is bare as seen from `git init --bare repo` but the clone of it should be non bare

Comment: @0andriy can you explain - i cant find anything related in the `man` and `info` pages. Also running `git flow` shows an error `git: 'flow' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: i am running `git` version `2.12.2`

Comment: https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/

Comment: Is this a deployment scenario? Will you modify contents of `/srv/web` or you want that repo to be barren only for having the actual files there 
 -- possibly serving for http access?

Comment: @infiniteRefactor yes, this is a deployement scenario. The contents of `/srv/web` will not be modified without a change in the repo. `/srv/web/` will be used for hosting a website within the lan.

Comment: @0andriy can you write an answer on how to use `git flow` to solve my problem. ^_^

Comment: What is your motivation for having two separate repositories rather than a single one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I mean is that everytime someone does a `git push` [to the bare repository in `/git/repo`,] the contents in [non-bare] `/srv/web/` should automatically update. Similarly, if the git repository is reverted back, then the files in `/srv/web` should also revert to that.

You have, in essence, two choices:

- Make `/git/repo` actively update `/srv/web`.  This `/git/repo` -> `/srv/web` path is a "push update" (not the same as `git push`, but might as well be): it has the "mastering" repository update the "slaving" one whenever there is an update available on the master side.
- Make `/srv/web` actively update from `/git/repo`.  This `/git/repo` <- `/srv/web` path is a "pull update" (not the same as `git pull`, unless you implement it that way, but might as well be): it has the slaving repository update from the mastering one at regular intervals.

Your second requirement ("if the git repository is reverted back") is rather mysterious.  A bare repository, by definition, has no work-tree; so no one can do any work in it.  It can only be updated by bringing in new commits from some other Git repository.  If someone wants to do a `git revert`, they do it in some *other* repository, and then `git push`.  So all updates to the bare repository should happen via `git push` and you should not *need* this second requirement.

Hence, I'll just ignore the second requirement entirely.

#### When and why to use one or the other

There's no particularly strong reason to favor either approach, but note that each has a different flaw.

- If you use push updates, and the receiver is down, the update never happens.  The master tries but fails to update the slave.  When the slave comes back up, the master just sits around until there's a *new* update.

  (If everything is on a single server, this problem goes away, and this method becomes the clear winner.)
- If you use pull updates, there is a time-lag: however long the pull interval is, the slave can remain out of date.  Furthermore, if the master goes down just before an update, the slave can remain out of date even longer than that.

#### Making `/srv/web` actively update from `/git/repo` (pull style update)

This is conceptually simpler.  You kist have your `/srv/web` *poll* your `/git/repo` for any interesting updates.  The poll frequency / interval determines how long it takes for the update to make it from point A to point B.  To make this faster, you could poll infrequently, but also have a triggering mechanism that you invoke from, e.g., a post-receive script: "I just got some important update; please poll now."  In other words, you use a hybrid of pull-and-push.

You can literally just run `git pull` from a crontab entry, for instance (though I recommend not using `git pull` ever, including here: break it up into `git fetch` followed by another Git command).

#### Making `/git/repo` actively update `/srv/web` (push style update)

[Edit: I got interrupted while writing the original answer, and mixed up the update and post-update hooks; this is now fixed.]

This is relatively straightforward, using a post-receive or post-update hook.  There is also an `update` hook but that's the wrong place to do this.  The difference between them all is I think illustrated best with an example:  What happens in `/git/repo` if I, as someone with push access to it, do this from my own Git clone:

```
git push origin 1234567:refs/heads/zorg 8888888:refs/tags/lucky
```

Here, I am telling my Git to contact your server Git (my `origin` = your `/git/repo`) and deliver my commit `1234567` to your Git.  My Git does so, along with any other objects required to make `1234567` useful.  I am also telling my Git to deliver commit-or-tag `8888888` to your Git, so my Git does that, along with any other objects required to make `8888888` useful.

Once your Git has all those objects, my Git asks your Git:

1. Please set your branch `zorg` (`refs/heads/zorg`) to `1234567`.
2. Please set your tag `lucky` (`refs/tags/lucky`) to `8888888`.

At this point, your Git will invoke your `pre-receive` hook, if you have one.  It delivers the old and new hash IDs for `refs/heads/zorg` and `refs/tags/lucky` on standard input.  Your pre-receive hook's job is to examine these and decide yea-or-nay: "allow all these updates to proceed to the next step" or "forbid any of these updates from occurring at all."

Next, your Git will invoke your `update` hook *twice* (again, if you have one).  One of these will say "hey, someone is asking to change `refs/heads/zorg`, here's the old and new hash values, should we let him?"  The other will say "hey, someone is asking to change `refs/tags/lucky`, here's the old and new hash values, should we let him?"  Your hook's job is to examine this one update and decide yea-or-nay: allow the update, or reject it.  If you allow one and reject the other, the one update occurs and the other fails.

Finally, after all of the updates have been accepted or rejected, for whatever updates actually *did* occur, your Git invokes your `post-receive` and `post-update` hooks (if those exist).  Your Git delivers to your post-receive hook, on standard input, one line for each update that did occur, in the same form it used in the `pre-receive` hook.  Your post-receive hook can do whatever it wants with these input lines, but it's too late to stop the updates from happening: they are already done.  Your `zorg` branch now points to commit `1234567` and your `lucky` tag now points to commit `8888888`, assuming your pre-receive and update hooks did not reject these.  Your Git delivers to your post-update hook, as arguments, one argument for each updated reference: `refs/heads/zorg` and `refs/tags/lucky`.

You may now take any action you like.

The obvious action to take, in the post-receive or post-update hook, is to trigger `/srv/web` to pick up the new commit(s) on any branch(es) you want it to update.  (The update hook is not suitable as, at hook time, the actual change has not yet happened, so if your `/srv/web` is *very* fast, it might not be able to *get* the new objects from your `/git/repo` yet: they may still in the process of being cemented into place.)

The actual implementation could be as simple as: "Ditch `$GIT_DIR` environment variable, cd into slave repository, and run `git pull`."  The reason to unset `GIT_DIR` is that any Git hook is run with this variable set, and it contains a relative path to the Git repository, which interferes with using other repositories.  As before, I recommend avoiding `git pull` entirely.

Also, be aware that the user-ID (i.e., privileges) of the user that is running the `post-receive` script depends on the authentication method used to do the `git push` in the first place.  This affects *all* deployment methods, even if the post-receive script simply sends a message (e.g., a packet on a socket port) to some independent process that does the slave-side update, since the privileges available to send a message may depend on user-ID.

#### Final note: do you really need a *Git repository* in the deployment area?

If your server is a typical Web server, it doesn't *need* a Git repository.  You can simply update the equivalent of a work-tree.  If your web server is on a different *system*, using a Git repository may be the simplest or most convenient way to achieve this, but if it is all on one machine, you can just run `git --work-tree=/path/to/work-tree checkout ...` from the bare repository.

(Note that what gets checked out, and how the update happens, depends on what is in the *index* and `HEAD` in the actual repository, and how the index compares to the supplied work-tree.  Additional arguments to `git checkout` may change which branch is to be checked-out, which will update `HEAD` correspondingly.)

Comment: I was about to write an answer suggesting the `--work-tree` method outlined in the "final note" section here. Unless the OP has requirements that I'm not seeing that seems like the best approach.

Comment: How much it takes to write such a long answer? Any idea?

Comment: @mallaudin: depends on how many interrupts there are (in this case, several cat interrupts and a bio-break ;-) )

Comment: Whenever I think I have understood git well and now I can answer questions, someone like @torek pops up with 96k repo and writes 1343 words answer. RIP me!

Comment: @mallaudin: a bunch of the above is not really Git-specific, it just ties into Git through things like hooks. The permissions stuff is especially troublesome sometimes. I never could get Git and web services to cooperate on SELinux with all the security turned on (this was about 10 years ago, not sure if it has improved since then).

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. This answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using git is not actually perfect fit for the scenario you envision for a couple of reasons.

First you are completely reversing the normal use of git. A git repository is actually a logical picture of your project. There might be branches in the project so this logical picture is much more complex then *latest version*. You need to *get* actual branch you want to a working copy and work on it. This is what non-bare repositories are about. They are *repository* and a *working copy*. It is not the intended use of git to push latest version to a working copy.

Second there are technical difficulties about pushing to a non-bare repository. As a default behavior git would deny pushing to a non-bare repository. However there are ways to configure your non-bare for that. But that configuration is only feasible if you'll never ever modify your non-bare working copy. If you begin to modify the working copy at non-bare you'll definitely start having problems.

Third, if you're willing to serve your working copy on web keep in mind that `.git` directory will be served too. This might cause vulnerabilities. If you'll do this I at least recommend serving a sub folder of your project if possible. This way `.git` is left out.

However I'll recommend you another method for doing all this. Instead of initializing a directory under the web tree as a repository you can simply auto copy all you working copy (without repository -- .git folder) to the desired directory. Since you are only interested in serving the files that would be a more suitable method.

At your repository `/git/repo`, there is a folder named `hooks`. Create file `/git/repo/hooks/post-receive` under this directory with the content

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /srv/web/*
git archive master | tar -x -C /srv/web
```

Also you need to give execute permission to this file.

```
chmod +x /git/repo/hooks/post-receive
```

Then after each push to this bare repo, HEAD of branch master will be copied to the directory of your choice without any repository information.

**Update:** I think the initial solution in the answer was not valid. So I removed it, alternative solution is still ok though.

**Update 2:** As @torek noticed this solution causes a small window of invalid content in the web directory. Since you indicated you'll serve the web content on local network, I guess that is not a problem. Moreover this is basically a kind of *poor man's deployment* scenario and should not be used any production deployment. However this can be improved with a temporary staging directory.

Replace the post-receive hook with the below script. This script reduces the time your `/srv/web` directory stays empty. Since `rm -rf` and `mv` are pretty fast (if your temp directory is on the same disk drive) and since repository size does not effect both commands the invalid content window will be smaller.

```
#!/bin/bash
STAGING=`mktemp -d`
git archive master | tar -x -C $STAGING
rm -rf /srv/web
mv $STAGING /srv/web
```

Or you can use a swap instead of deleting the folder first as @torek suggested.

```
#!/bin/bash
STAGING=`mktemp -d`
SWAP=`mktemp -d`
git archive master | tar -x -C $STAGING
mv /srv/web $SWAP
mv $STAGING /srv/web
rm -rf $SWAP
```

However note that you are deleting or swapping `/srv/web` and you'll lose any ownership, permission or ACL information of the folder if you follow this method.

You can alternatively use rsync which will still copy the files, but since it will operate selectively whole content will not be deleted at any instant. Also `rsync` can be tuned to preserve ownership, permissions, etc.

```
#!/bin/bash
STAGING=`mktemp -d`
git archive master | tar -x -C $STAGING
rsync -a --delete --remove-source-files $STAGING /srv/web
```

Comment: The `git archive` method works pretty well, but note one other caveat: `tar -x -C /srv/web` will extract files that *are* in the archive, but won't *remove* files that are in the target tree but are *not* in the archive. Sometimes this is what you want, but not always.

Comment: @torek I think the `rm -rf..` before `git archive` handles these _removed_ files.

Comment: Ah, yes, didn't see that. That opens up a small time window when the web server has no files. There's always a race, no matter how you handle this, but one method I like to keep the race as small as possible is to build the new server files in a new directory, then swap the directories and remove the old one.

Comment: @torek thanks for the idea, I've updated the question to suggest a couple of other alternatives. I'm adding the swap idea to them too.

Comment: Thank you @infiniteRefactor